# Given a number of 4 digits , How to print in the screen the unit , dozen , hundred and thousand of that number?

Tags: c

I'm really new at C and I was doing an exercise where I was supposed to print the unit  , dozen , hundred and thousand of a number.
(Ex : 1234 => Unit = 4 ; Dozen = 3 ; Hundred = 2 ; Thousand = 1.)

**This is what I came up with :**

```
int main ()
{ 
    int number , reminder , unit , dozen , hundred , thousand;  
    
    printf ("Type a number with a maximum of 4 digits : ");
    scanf ("%d" , &number);
         
    while (number)
    { reminder = number%10;
      number = number/10;
      printf ("Number : %d Reminder : %d\n", number , reminder); 
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**The output looks like this** :

> Type a number with a maximum of 4 digits: 1234
>
> Number : 123  Reminder : 4
>
> Number : 12 Reminder : 3
>
> Number : 1 Reminder : 2
>
> Number : 0 Reminder : 1

I used the remainder so that I can separate the numbers. **I wanted the output to be like this** :

> Type a number with a maximum of 4 digits : 1234
>
> Unit = 4
>
> Dozen = 3
>
> Hundred = 2
>
> Thousand = 1

**Any suggestions on how I can get this problem solved?**

Comment: So, you seem to have solved the problem, but you just need to create an array of strings to store the names of the parts, and then increment an index into that array every loop.

Comment: I don't think you meant `dozen` because that's base 12... you meant `tens`

Comment: Create an array of strings `char unitname[4][42];int i=0;`, populate it with `sprintf()` and print with `printf ("%s : %d\n", unitname[i], reminder);i++;`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With just a few tweaks you can do it like this. I have used a string array `digname[]` for the description of each digit value. And I made sure the loop ends when `number > 9999` by using `power` which also indexes the string array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXPOWER 4

int main ()
{ 
    char *digname[MAXPOWER] = {"Units", "Tens", "Hundreds", "Thousands"};
    int number = 0, remainder, power = 0;  

    printf ("Type a number with a maximum of 4 digits : ");
    scanf ("%d" , &number);

    while (number) {
        remainder = number % 10;
        printf ("%s: %d\n", digname[power], remainder); 
        number = number / 10;
        if (++power >= MAXPOWER)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The example program entered more than 4 digits:

```
Type a number with a maximum of 4 digits : 12345
Units: 5
Tens: 4
Hundreds: 3
Thousands: 2
```

Comment: And who will cop to down voting, and why please? We can only improve our quality if we know what is wrong.